# Azure ML Studio Error CammandLine exceeds Limit

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, k-means

I am setting up ML experiment in Azure ML Studio Designer for K-Means Clustering and have ~750 attributes that I am attempting to cluster with ~4000 rows.

When i go to execute this i get the following error:

```
AzureMLCompute job failed.
InvalidPropertyValue: The size of the specified property Job.Properties.CustomToolkitSettings.CommandLine 
exceeds the limit of 20480 characters
```

There isn't much on this error but would someone be able to assist me on how to increase the limit? I don't believe this is an K-Means error but a Azure ML Studio error.